# Regular expression in R for finding spaces ONLY after a known word

Tags: r, regex, spaces

I have several character vectors like these in R:

```
a <- "text text NOTE      3/1"
b <- "text NOTE   4.3%"
```

All of them have a known word - `NOTE` - which is followed by a variate number of spaces and other characters.

What I want to do is to find the spaces between `NOTE` and other characters in string, and then replace each space with another character - say `@`

The desired output would be:

```
"text text NOTE@@@@@@3/1"
"text NOTE@@@4.3%"
```

So far I could only find the regular expression that will find `NOTE` and the spaces that follow it.

```
c <- gsub("NOTE\\s+", "@", a)
c
[1] "@3/1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|NOTE)\\K\\s", "@", a, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQNbAV/2) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/QgWSRs).

```r
a <- "text text NOTE      3/1"
b <- "text NOTE   4.3%"
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|NOTE)\\K\\s", "@", a, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "text text NOTE@@@@@@3/1"
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|NOTE)\\K\\s", "@", b, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "text NOTE@@@4.3%"
```

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|NOTE)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `NOTE`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `\s` - a whitespace char.

Here is a `stringr` version where the whitespaces matched after `NOTE` are each replaced with a `@` char in the `function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s", "@")` callback function:

```r
library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace_all(a, "NOTE\\s+", function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s", "@"))
# => [1] "NOTE@@@@@@3/1"
stringr::str_replace_all(b, "NOTE\\s+", function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s", "@"))
# => [1] "NOTE@@@4.3%"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The character vectors I mentioned are actually substrings. I've edited my question.

Comment: @Rafael As I wrote in the initial answer, you just needed to remove `^` (I even removed it in the `stringr` version).

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `[[:space:]]` like this:

```r
a <- "NOTE      3/1"
b <- "NOTE   4.3%"

lapply(list(a,b), function(x) gsub("[[:space:]]", "@", x))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "NOTE@@@@@@3/1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "NOTE@@@4.3%"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answering. The character vectors I mentioned are actually substrings. I've edited my question.